# Read gz file as a string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gzip

I have been searching for a way that could read gz file in python, and I did something like

```
with gzip.open(filepath) as infile:
    ...
```

However, it seems like the read-in data is byte-like and I cannot do something like `for l in infile`. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass `mode='rt'` (text mode) to the [`gzip.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open) call.

From the documentation (linked above):

> The mode argument can be any of `'r', 'rb', 'a', 'ab', 'w', 'wb', 'x'` or `'xb'` for binary mode, or `'rt', 'at', 'wt',` or `'xt'` for text mode. The default is `'rb'`.